# how to write text to file in HDFS without appending

Tags: linux, bash, hadoop, hdfs, bigdata

I wrote the following cli in order to write version to `HDFS` on remote machine

Note - The following CLI is also create the file - `/user/version`

```
echo $version 
0.21

ssh $remote_machine "su hdfs -c \"echo $version | hadoop fs -appendToFile - /user/version\" "
```

I give explain about the Cli

I am using ssh to remote machine in order to write the content of the variable - $version to `/user/version` ( while `/user/version` is `HDFS` file )

cli succeeded but this approach appending the version when cli run couple of times , and what we want is write the version without appending

example what we got ( on the remote machine )

```
su hdfs
$ hdfs dfs -cat /user/version
0.21
0.21
0.21
```

while the expected output should be

```
su hdfs
$ hdfs dfs -cat /user/version
0.21
```

summary:

cli should create the HDFS file - `/user/version` , and write the $version to file

Comment: Is `-appendToFile` right option?

Comment: no this isn't the right option but it close to what I want

Comment: Have you tried replacing `-appendToFile` with `-put`?

Comment: yes I did but I get - File exists

Comment: what I means is that when I run it in the first time its ok , but when I run it on the second time I get -  File exists  ( cli should be re-run )

Comment: Have you tired replacing `-appendToFile` with `-copyFromLocal -f`?

Comment: no this approach is new for me , can you give example with full syntax?

Comment: as I understand - copyFromLocal means copy from current OS to HDFS , but this isnt what we need , we not need to copy local file to hdfs , only create new file in HDFS and file in HDFS should contain the #version

Comment: Have you tired `-put -f`?

Comment: yes now I try it , and this option works , great -:)   ( the flag -f , do the different , its like force )

Comment: you can post an answer and I will select your answer

Comment: I don't know anything about HDFS, I just know how to operate Google.

Comment: ok , so I will post the solution that you give me just for avryone that want to see